# Regex a ruby block argument and all instances within the block

Tags: ruby, regex, sublimetext2, textmate

I have been trying to develop a regex to match a block's argument, and then all the instances of that argument.

Using this example:

```
File.open(inFile).each do |line|
  line.chomp!
    if line.empty? then
      next
    elsif line =~ /^>/
      line.slice!(/>/)
      names.push(line)
    elsif line !~ /^>/
      seqs.push(line)
    end             
end
```

I would like to match the word between the pipes, `line`, and then all instances of `line`.

Matching the argument is simple:

```
(?<=\|)(\w*?)(?=\|)
```

But I am really unsure how to use this match as a pattern for the rest of the document.

Any thoughts on how to proceed are welcome.

(Edit 2: I am now not concerned with limiting the scope of the regex to the block.  I would like to match all instances in the whole document.  Please consider re-examining this simpler question.)

(Edit:  I am trying to incorporate this regex into a `tmLanguage` file for textmate/sublime.  This way, the argument and all instances are the same color.  I am sure there is a way to construct a plugin to do this, but I haven't tried yet, short of looking how the sublime plugin `bracketHighlighter` works.)

Comment: You need to provide some test data and an expected output to get a good answer to this question.

Comment: Expected output is clearly stated in my original question.

Comment: I don't see any, hence the request.

Comment: Seriously? "I would like to match the word between the pipes, `line`, and then all instances of `line` within the block,"

Comment: That's not an _example_ of the output, that's a _description_ of the output. Seriously.

Comment: I think you are purposefully being obtuse.  Both the description and  example are the same thing.  A regex match.

Comment: A regular expression _match_ is the part of the _input_ data matched by applying a regex _pattern_. So there are 3 things, the _input_, the _pattern_, and the _output_ (i.e. match). In the comment above, you gave a written _description_ of the thing to _match_ i.e. a portion of the (ungiven) _input_. You've also provided a pattern (`(?<=\|)(\w*?)(?=\|)`) and unless this is the _input_ or the resulting _match_ then you haven't provided the _example(s)_ I requested. -1.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Seriously. It won't work reliably, and you'll spend more time proofreading and fixing the results than you would making the changes by hand.

Comment: I agree, it's not ideal.  I'll edit my post to explain my rationale for trying.  Thanks glenn.

Comment: Think about all the contexts in which `line` could appear. Now all the places `end` could appear, never mind potential `{}` pairs. You're trying to write a Ruby language parser inside a regular expression. Unless you have some vastly simplifying assumptions you can make due to your particular situation, it's hopeless.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Please consider looking at the edited question, which now just looks to match the argument across the whole document.

Comment: But the "whole document" will presumably have lots of other `|x|`s. As might even a single block. So I don't think you've really simplified things.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the Ruby language bundle and see which names have already been assigned matches, you'll find the first part has already been done:

```
name: variable.other.block.ruby
match: [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

You can use that name to refer to block local vars, probably as `source.ruby.variable.other.block.ruby`. I'm not sure how you'll refer to the different matches of a multi argument list.

I'll keep the downvote on the question because it's incredibly unclear that you're trying to parse the *language itself*, rather than the input from the file.